# Does the Hauptsatz of a Relativsatz follow the same rules of verb placement as a regular sentence?

Tags: word-order, relative-clause

Here’s the sentence I was making:

> Können Sie jemanden in München empfehlen, der diesen Wasserfilter installieren kann?

For some reason, the Hauptsatz doesn’t feel right to me – is it?

Comment: There were a few other issues with the sentence, but the word order is completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking your sentence is ok, but I as a german would say:

> Können Sie **mir** jemanden in München empfehlen, der diesen/dieses Wasserfilter installieren kann?

I think you missed '*mir*' as a personal pronoun to which person someone should recommend something. This makes the sentence more clear and fluent to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the main clause of a relative clause follows the same word-order rules it would follow if the relative (or less specifically: the subordinate clause) were not there.

So always build a main clause according to V2 (verb in second position) unless it is an imperative or a question. Your example sentence is a question, so the verb coming first is perfect.

If you’re interested what the non-question form of the sentence would be:

> Sie können mir jemanden in München empfehlen, der diesen Wasserfilter installieren kann.

There is one tiny catch you need to be aware of: If the sentence starts with the subordinate clause, that is considered to be the first fragment of the main clause and the verb must come second.

> Wer den Wasserfilter installieren kann, verdient eine Empfehlung.